# TFS Error message: Folder already in use

Tags: tfs

I am getting a below error message when I map a folder in TFS,

[image: error message]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS is telling you that the folder you have chosen is already mapped to another workspace.  You can review your workspaces from Visual Studio in Source Control Explorer.

Basically, you can't have the same folder on your machine mapped by two different workspaces.

Comment: Earlier, I have mapped TFS folder to my machine, but i have removed my mapping after some time, but now when i again mapped this to another folder then its through me this error message.

Comment: You could try using TFS Sidekicks http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/ and use the Workspace sidekick to delete the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to `remove your old mapping workspace not used` or dettach your workspace, you have print describes how remove workspace
[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, I have checked this steps but noting is display in this workspaces details, when edit workspaces like this then its display me my other 2 mapping which are mapped with other folder.

Comment: @Priyank be sure to log in as Administrator; the message is indicating that the conflicting working folder mapping is in a workspace owned by Administrator.

Comment: @Edward, can you please update, how can i remove my old mapping. its not display old mapping in my workspace,